# Desire2Learn Valence API for External Learning Tools

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a Valence API call we can use to retrieve the instance id and the instance name for each instance of a specified External Learning Tool in a specified course?

Answer (score 0):

There is no tight connection connection between external tools links and a course. It is possible to query all the topic links to find external tool links that have been used at the topic level. However, external links could be present within the html documents of the course content as well, so to be comprehensive you would have to parse and scan all those documents. So while "possible" its going to be a brute force effort.